# Load data from database in model instance

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

is there a way to load data from DB from inside of instantiated model using Doctrine 2.x ?

Implementation in `load()` method:

```
$model = new Model();
$model->load($params);
```

`$param` = `array` with key => value pair which will be used to find data in DB, ex.: `$param = array('id' => 1)`

`find()` method from `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` doesn't allow to pass instances and i could not find anything else.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is `$params`, an array? What does load do, opulate the model with raw data? If you just want to refresh your entity with the data from the database your code should be placed in a custom repository extending `EntityRepository`. You get the repository from the entity manager, pass your existing entity to a method like `refreshModel($model)` which fetches the data from the db and updates the entity and returns it.

Comment: I've updated question. I don't want to update this model, i need to load raw data from DB to existing object instance using it's method (`load()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately loading data in instantiated object is not possible.

Workaround method is:

```
public function load($id = 0)
{
    $resultObject = $this->_getEntityManager()->find(get_class($this), $id);

    if ($resultObject) {
        foreach (get_object_vars($resultObject) as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }

        unset($resultObject);
    }

    return $this;
}
```